# How do I solve my weak wifi signal problem on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, realtek, realtek-wireless

I've been facing this problem for a long time. The signal is so low that id doesn't work if I keep my phone away for like 10 metres. Signal is not even full, if I just keep my phone less that 1 metre. Is there any solution for this or do I have to install OS? Does installing OS from the scratch helps? I tried this [guide](https://connectwww.com/how-to-solve-realtek-rtl8723be-weak-wifi-signal-problem-in-ubuntu/4625/) two times, but it doesn't work, it only increases the strength by like 2-3%. I have fibre net in other room but it doesn't even catch the signal, so that's the deal.

Here is the specs that I get by keeping my phone as close as possible:

**iwconfig**

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"myphone"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 20:82:C0:6B:19:9A   
          Bit Rate=7.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=20/70  Signal level=-90 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:80   Missed beacon:0

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.
```

**Edit**:
Some more details:

```
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.

   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 3160
   vendor: Intel Corporation

   Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev 93)`
```

Comment: a wifi repeater from your fivre router?

Comment: sorry didn't get you?

Comment: Is there a way of extending your fibre router from its current location to where the signal is weak either using a wifi bridge or rj45 connection between the two routers?